# How to Use MYSQL IN Operator to fetch multiple records through php array

Tags: php

```
 $region_arr=array('Capital','ABC','Def');
 $RegionStr = implode(',', $region_arr);
 $sql="SELECT tax_id from bf_taxes where tax_region IN ('$RegionStr')";
```

This query is not working for me And when echoed it The result was

```
 SELECT tax_id from bf_taxes where tax_region IN ('Capital,ABC,DEF');
```

Which is wrong.The Query Should have been

```
 SELECT tax_id from bf_taxes where tax_region IN ('Capital','ABC','DEF');
```

Then the query would have given me the accurate result.So suggest me the changes i need to make in my code to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Suggesting you to write your implode so that it adds the missing quotes...

Comment: This code is open to SQL injection and you should look into using prepared statements and bind variables.

Comment: @NigelRen i am using active records this was for the sake of example

Comment: If your using binds though, your sql would be `SELECT tax_id from bf_taxes where tax_region IN (?,?,?);` which is a very different thing to what your trying to achieve.

Comment: @Talha Sarwar my answer worked for you?

Comment: @BeingSunny Yes Sir totally appreciate the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this by preceding the quotes(') before and after the regions,

```
$region_arr=array('Capital','ABC','Def');
$RegionStr = "'".implode("','", $region_arr)."'"; //see this line
$sql="SELECT tax_id from bf_taxes where tax_region IN ($RegionStr);";
echo $sql;
```

**Output:**

SELECT tax_id from bf_taxes where tax_region IN ('Capital','ABC','Def');